# Configurate RouterLink in a botton

Tags: angular, router, routerlink

I'm practicing Angular 2, and configured a button with a password entered and a correct one to redirect to a second page. I configured the routing but I do not know how to do it so that it is validated and then redirected.

What I currently have configured in the following but I can not click the button and I would like to redirect to the second page.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you having both routerLink and click on the same button. you can instead move the routerLink to the code as

```
validarpass(pass:number) {
    .....
    this.router.navigate(['/component-one']);   
}
```

Inject the Router to your constructor as below

```
constructor(private router:Router){
...}
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer  Aravind. I could resolve my problem :)

Comment: That's all for the moment @Aravind XD
I'm learning to program and, That is my first program. I want to simulate an ATM :)